# Wordpress Admin - Plugin's back-end stylesheets not loading

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, backend

I've a problem with a WP admin area and its plugins.

It seems that the plugins' stylesheets used on WP back-end don't load. While general WP admin area CSS is loading correctly. That wouldn't be a big issue but some styles affect important functionalities (specially Advanced Custom Fields).

Basically, there's a massive list on the back-end  pages with this missing href attribute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

- All the plugins are up to date.
- All the plugins's CSS files are where they're supposed to.
- The website is using a quite old theme for the front-page.

I've been thinking of two different solutions:

- Ideally, fixing these broken links.
- Otherwise, manually add the most important stylesheets somehow to the back-end theme.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time guys!

Marc

Answer (score 1):

This is very late, but I had this same issue. It turned out that an old theme (circa 2015) was using an old version of the "Soil" plugin. If you disable the "clean-up" module (or the plugin entirely), this should get your stylesheets working.